# Tengo las macros activadas pero al insertar una acción, la opcion ejecutar macro no se puede seleccionar | PowerPoint2007

Tags: macros

¡Hola!
Tengo las macros habilitadas, pero cuando a una imagen le configuro la acción no puedo seleccionar **Ejecutar macro**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba seleccionando otra opcion que no sea "ninguna" en el mouse

Comment: @Gabriel si selecciono otra opción diferente a "ninguna" me sigue sin dejar poder seleccionar la opción ejecutar programa

Comment: Pueba desactivar las macros una por una, puede ser que alguna de las que tengas activas te impida habilitar la opción o incluso puede ser que tener tantas activadas a la vez sea el problema

Comment: @Gabriel, he probado como dices pero me sigue sin funcionar, si se te ocurre algo más por favor dímelo

Comment: Al final me ha funcionado, gracias @Gabriel